apt list --upgradable and USN
Below command gives the list of security patches which are available to apply.
apt list --upgradable | grep security | awk '{print $1}'
My expectation is that this list should be a subset of USN notices.
But I see that there are few packages which are in list but are not on USN site.
Underlying distribution is Jammy and concerned package is bsdutils. Though it is just one of the many such packages.
Snippet for apt command output is as:
accountsservice/jammy-updates,jammy-security 22.07.5-2ubuntu1.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 22.07.5-2ubuntu1.4]
bash/jammy-updates,jammy-security 5.1-6ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.1-6ubuntu1]
bsdextrautils/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.37.2-4ubuntu3]
bsdutils/jammy-updates,jammy-security 1:2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:2.37.2-4ubuntu3]
curl/jammy-updates,jammy-security 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.16 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.15]
eject/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.37.2-4ubuntu3]
fdisk/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.37.2-4ubuntu3]

And the link where I am expecting this list is: jammy USN
If my expectation is correct then please help me to resolve this puzzle.
